# Basename not working with xargs place holder

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I am trying to use `basename` utility in `xargs` piped from `printf` as below:

```
printf "%s" "$ACTUAL_FILES" | xargs -d ' ' -i  printf "%s\n" "$(basename {})"
```

Here `$ACTUAL_FILES` is an array of absolute file paths, each delimited with a space.

With the above snippet I am trying to print filename without path in each line. But the output I am getting is same as in `$ACTUAL_FILES` with each element in new line.

I know that we can achieve this with `bash sub shell` and `echo` with `xargs`, but I was informed to use `printf` with `xargs`.

How can I use basename or any other utility to get the filename.

Comment: The shell will expand `"$(basename {})"` before passing it to `xargs` as an argument.

Comment: @Abhinay: Wouldn't  a `... xargs -d ' ' basename` be sufficient?

Comment: Note that the `-d` and `-i` options are non-standard.

Comment: @ user1934428 it did not work that way.  Aslo, in future some more variables will be included to printf statement. Hence I am supposed to use printf.

Comment: If `ACTUAL_FILES` is really an array, the way to expand it is `"${ACTUAL_FILES[@]}"`. Probably also prefer lower case for your private variables; see [Correct Bash and shell script variable capitalization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/673055/correct-bash-and-shell-script-variable-capitalization)

Answer (score 2):

You need to strip the path after processing xargs (I write your var in lowercase):

```
printf "%s" "${actual_files}" | xargs -d ' ' -i  printf "%s\n" "{}" | sed 's#.*/##'
```

Processing can be easier when you start with replacing spaces by newlines.

```
tr ' ' '\n' <<< "${actual_files}"| sed 's#.*/##'
```

You can avoid `tr` with

```
grep -Eo "[^/]*( |$)" <<< "${actual_files}"
```

Answer (score 0):

`xargs` sends your arguments directly to the command. There is no shell intervention anymore when `xargs` makes the arguments and sends them to the command. Using `xargs` you cannot make use of a subshell call (`$(..)`). You can either preparse them before sending them to xargs, or you can let xargs make a shell instead in which you can make use of all the shell features.

```
printf "%s" "$ACTUAL_FILES" | xargs -d ' ' -i  bash -c 'printf "%s\n" "$(basename {})"'
```

If it is possible for you to use, GNU parallel comes with much more features in building a command.

```
printf "%s" "$ACTUAL_FILES" | parallel -q printf "%s\n" "{/}"
```

In here {/} automatically is the basename of the input arguments and -q preserves the quoting used.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you want to run `basename` for each matched file.  The best way to do this is for `xargs` to invoke a small shell script:

```
xargs -d ' ' -L1 sh -c 'printf "%s\n" "$(basename "$1")"' basename
```

You can improve performance by looping within the shell script, instead of starting a new shell for each match:

```
xargs -d ' ' sh -c 'for i; do printf "%s\n" "$(basename "$i")"; done' basename
```

Comment: The `printf` is kind of useless as well; simply running `xargs -n 1 basename` would do the same more economically.

Comment: @tripleee, yes of course - I'm assuming that printing is a [mcve] simplification of some more useful operation.

Answer (score 0):

If you have GNU coreutils, you could just:

```
IFS=' '; basename -a $ACTUAL_FILES
```

You could ignore the `IFS=' '` if you don't have any tabs nor newlines, or you could first use `readarray -d ' '` to split it and then pass to basename.